# Letter frequency by using map container

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, data-structures

I am attempting to define a class named Frequency by using map container as a data structure. The class is intended to read characters from the keyboard and count the frequency of each character that has been input.

[image: This]

This shows the UML diagram for the class Frequency.
The function printFreqTable should print the frequency of each input character as shown in the sample output:

```
Enter your string without spaces: textEPF
Char   Frequency
E      *
P      *
F      *
t      **
e      *
x      *
```

However, my implementation does not produce any outputs, and exists with code -1073741819. I was also wondering if there is a more efficient method of implementation that uses a map container.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Frequency {
public:
    Frequency();
    void insertStringtoMap();
    void printFreqTable();
    void readString();
private:
    typedef map <char, string, less <char > > mid;
    mid CMap;
    string s;
};

Frequency::Frequency()
{
    readString();
}

void Frequency::readString()
{
    cout << "Enter your string without spaces: ";
    getline(cin, s);
    cout << endl;
}

void Frequency::insertStringtoMap()
{
    int si = s.size();
    char str[50];
    strcpy_s(str, s.c_str());
    string freq = 0;

    for (char ch = 65; ch <= 122; ch++) {
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < si; i++)
        {
            if (ch == str[i])
            {
                c++;
            }
        }
        if (c > 0)
        {
            for (int star = 0; star < c; star++)
            {
                freq = freq + "*";

            }       
            CMap.insert(mid::value_type(ch, freq));
        }
    }
}

void Frequency::printFreqTable()
{
    cout << "Char\tFrequency";
    for (auto iter = CMap.cbegin(); iter != CMap.end(); ++iter)
        {
            cout << iter->first << "\t"
            << iter->second << "\n";
        }
}

int main()
{
    Frequency f;
    f.insertStringtoMap();
    f.printFreqTable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed to counting the occurrences of each character instead of building the graphical representation directly. When the counting is done I've used std::string's capability to create a string with n copies of a certain character to create the diagram.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Frequency {
public:
    Frequency();
    void insertStringtoMap();
    void printFreqTable();
    void readString();
private:
    typedef std::map<char, size_t> mid;
    mid CMap;
    std::string s;
};

Frequency::Frequency() :
    CMap(),
    s()
{
    readString();
}

void Frequency::readString()
{
    std::cout << "Enter your string without spaces: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void Frequency::insertStringtoMap() {
    for(auto ch : s) {
        ++CMap[ch];
    }
}

void Frequency::printFreqTable()
{
    std::cout << "Char\tFrequency\n";
    for (const auto& e : CMap)
    {
        std::cout << e.first << "\t" << std::string(e.second, '*') << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    Frequency f;
    f.insertStringtoMap();
    f.printFreqTable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues with your code.
**First:**

```
string freq = 0; //Assigning an int literal to a string?
```

It should simply be:

```
string freq;
```

**Second:**
This should be inside the first `for` loop next to `int c = 0;` so that you reset the count of `*`s for each character.

```
for (char ch = 65; ch <= 122; ch++) {
    int c = 0;
    string freq;
```

**Third:**
This is just to make the output look better, add a new line in this statement like this:

```
cout << "Char\tFrequency\n";
```

Output:

```
Enter your string without spaces: asdsadfkdfgag

Char    Frequency
a       ***
d       ***
f       **
g       **
k       *
s       **
```

As a good practice, stop using `using namespace std`.  See this question and its answers: [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting confused by trying to do too many things at once.

Split your problem into 2 parts: read the string and store each occurrence in the map, and print the resulting map in a pretty format.

Now you can parse the string into the map easily, simply loop over each character and add an entry to the map - which can be anything, so a `std::map<char, int>` will store an int (ie of occurrences) against each key entry, which can be the character itself

do this by resolving the map entry and incrementing the value, eg `mymap[letter]++` or `mymap.find(letter) += 1`

then work on the formatting, by iterating through the map, printing the same number of stars as the int value.

(in pseudocode:)

```
std::map<char,int>::iterator i = mymap.begin()
while (i != mymap.end()) {
  cout i.first << "*" (i.second) times << endl;
  i++;
}
```

Don't bother storing the * string in the map, just keep a note of the number of occurrences and use that to generate the star string when needed. That's much more efficient, and you can also change your formatting very easily.

notes: use a typedef for your map which makes things look and read much easier. Std::string has a constructor that easily lets you generate a number of stars in a string.